# Sampling from a truncated normal distribution in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, scipy

I'm porting a bunch of calculations from Numpy/Scipy to TensorFlow and I need to generate samples from a [truncated normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution), the equivalent of `scipy.stats.truncnorm.rvs()`.

I think that the two standard ways to generate these samples are by rejection sampling or by feeding truncated *uniform* distribution samples to the inverse normal cumulative distribution function, but the former seems difficult to implement within a static computation graph (we can't know how many rejection loops to run until we generate the samples) and I don't think there is an inverse normal cumulative distribution function in the standard TensorFlow libraries.

I realize that there is a function in TensorFlow called `truncated_normal()`, but that simply clips at two standard deviations; you can't specify the lower and upper limits.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simpler might be to embed the functions you're used to in the TensorFlow graph using `tf.py_func`. And in case you need it, you can just set the seed as usual  using the `numpy.random` module:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from scipy.stats import truncnorm

np.random.seed(seed=123)

a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
size = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)

f = tf.py_func(lambda x, y, s: truncnorm.rvs(x, y, size=s),
               inp=[a, b, size],
                Tout=tf.float64)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(f, {a:0, b:1, size:10}))
```

will print:

```
[0.63638154 0.24732635 0.19533476 0.49072188 0.66066675 0.37031253
 0.9732229  0.62423404 0.42385328 0.34206036]
```

Comment: Thanks, @Nicolas. This worked for me. Until the TensorFlow folks implement a native TensorFlow version of this distribution, I will use this solution.